# How to implement lazy loading in Lit (Web Components)

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading, lit-element, lit-html

I want to create a reusable web components library made with Lit. These elements will be used with React, Angular, Vue and other framework as well. Now there is a problem, I am bundling these components using webpack and it is generating bundle file of each component in "dist" dir. I want this lib to have lazy loading feature. Like, I am using button only its bundle file should be requested over network.

The user have to just include my lib in the project, user will be able to use these components. Only the bundle of those particular web components which has been used should be called.

I have used stencilJS as well. In its config file, I have used:

```
{
 type:dist,
 esmLoader: '../loader'
}
bundles:[
{components:['component-one']},
{components:['component-one']}
]
```

Using this in Stencil we can have individual bundle files of each component which type: dist handles lazy loading & it also have the entry file.

Similar thing I want to implement using Lit. This means consumer should not have to worry about lazy loading in react, angular. It should be handled in the lib (Lit).

Comment: How you implement lazy loading is up to you. At the most basic level, components can be used in HTML before they are loaded, and then a dynamic import of the chunk will cause them to be initialized on definition.
E.g. https://shoelace.style/getting-started/installation#cdn-installation-easiest has an autoloader.

At a high level, their autoloader uses a mutation observer on the document and watches for addition of HTML elements. Then if a tag name matches one that should be loaded, they load the required chunk. That might be a good starting point.

Comment: @YouCodeThings Thanks for the reply. But I think that is like hard coding things. if I am designing web component system for my organisation is it possible to do that one by one and handling multiple things manually.